# Http Post param in url angular 2

Tags: angular, http, url, post, parameters

So, I have the next code in Javascript where value is send in the URL

```
//params = 5
function httpPostAsync(url, params){
    // test: curl -X POST http://url/brightness/5
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", "/brightness/"+ params , true);

    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            //Popup good for debugging
        }
    }
    http.send(null);
}
```

My question is, how can I do this in Angular ?
I have the next code, but it doesn´t send the value '5' in the URL

//Service

```
  postValue(data) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('value', data);
    return this.http.post(url, params.toString(), options)
      .timeoutWith(2000);
  }
```

//Component

```
let value = 5;
this._localserverService.postValue(value).subscribe();
```

I know that when I send data with form-urlencoded content type, I should send the data in query string format with key=value pairs. But this was not needed in my old code.

I also know that the second parameter of http.post is the body of the message (the payload) and not the URL search parameters.

What should I do different?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you simply append `data` to your URL:

```
postValue(data) {
    // You might not even need to set the header, as you body is anyway empty...
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(`url/${data}`, null, options)
      .timeoutWith(2000);
  }
```

`URLSearchParams` is used for query string parameters (so something like `http://url/brightness?value=5`), but if you want the `5` as a section of the URL (so `http://url/brightness/5`), the code above should do it.

Comment: I dindn´t know that was possible. Thanks!